# New custom actions not found in Install4J 5.1.9

Tags: java, install4j

I am using Install4J version 5.1.9, recently upgraded from 5.0.10. I want to add a new custom action to my installation. I have an existing jar file that contains custom actions that I added using previous versions. I have created a new Action class and made sure it extends AbstractInstallAction and overrides the Install method. I have built the jar and verified that this Action class is present in the jar.

When I run the Install4J GUI I have verified that the jar that contains the new Action class is present as an Archive in the list of Custom Code & Resources. I try to add the custom action (via Search Action in Custom Code), but it is not listed (only actions I have used before are listed).

I can modify existing actions, e.g. by adding a pop up dialog, so I know Install4J is reading the Jar file. Is there any reason why Install4J might not be finding my new custom action?

Edit: I have tried to create a simple action so I can be sure that the error is not with the action. This my action code:

```
package a.b.c.install4j.installation;

import com.install4j.api.actions.AbstractInstallAction;
import com.install4j.api.context.InstallerContext;
import com.install4j.api.context.UserCanceledException;

public class TestAction extends AbstractInstallAction {

    @Override
    public boolean install(InstallerContext installerContext) throws UserCanceledException {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This action is not picked up either, but is present in the jar file Install4J is checking.

Comment: Try looking for the file %TEMP%/install4j_error.log, maybe it contains an error that occurred while loading the class.

Comment: I check that log file, but found no errors that looked related. I removed the log file, reran Install4J, tried to add the action, but the error log file was not created. I assume this is because no error was thrown during the add custom action  process?

Comment: For completeness, the errors in the file were all: Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the file is only crated if there was an error. Please send you custom code jar file to support@ej-technologies.com and we'll have a look at it.

Comment: UPDATE: An old JAR file was referenced in Installer->Custom code & Resources which did not contain the class `TestAction`.